# XML Schema Expression

Tags: xml, regex

Am trying to validate the following:

```
</xs:element>
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="Surname">
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="70"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Does the above implies I can only accept 3 Letters?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow exactly three letters then don't forget to add anchors.

```
"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$"
```

OR

```
"^[a-zA-Z]{3}$"
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  So of what importance or purpose is the 'pattern value' my code above please?